# Asserting and Messages -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

So when I'm running rails tests I want to print things to the console like

```
Test1: passed
Test2: F1
Test3: F2
```

Right now I have some code going that reads like

```
test "the first test" do
    print "\nTest1: "
    assert true
    print "passed"
end
```

That works well for the test that pass, but I have no clue how to get a counter going for the Faliures because as soon as it asserts false the test ends.

At the moment my output looks like this...

```
Test0: passed.
Test1: F
Test2: F
```

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: Just to get some context, why are you doing this? TestUnit will give you a summary of failure and pass after the run

Comment: The person I'm making this for wants it this way. So they can look at the number after the 'F' and know which error it is instead of counting the F's until they find which error they want to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to manually do the check before the assertion happens

```
test "the first test" do
    print "\nTest1: "
    condition = false
    print "F1" unless condition
    assert condition
    print "Passed"
end
```

Comment: This will turn out to be

    Test1: F1F